# Python site-packages folder: recommended location, ownership, group, and permissions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

I am using python 2.7.10 and python 3.4.2 on mac osx 10.10.5.
Previously I just installed python packages using `sudo pip install` without thinking much about it, but recently I ran into trouble.

Some packages didn't want to install (some errors I don't recall), so my colleague suggested to update pip.

As `pip install --upgrade pip` didn't work (the error was this: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'`) I used `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`, which worked.
However, afterwards when I tried to use pip I got `ImportError: No module named pip` although `which pip` `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Of course `sudo pip list` works.

Currently, all my packages in the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` folder are `root` `wheel` with various permissions, python is here: `/usr/bin/python`.

In the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages` folder, my packages are owned by me OR `root`, but all have group `admin` and again various permission rights. Python 3 is here: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3`.

I did some research to figure out the correct way of handling the site-packages folder and I found several suggestions from `sudo chmod 755 -R /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` to `sudo chown -R YOURUSERNAME /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and various warnings why this should not be done. Of course, there are also several warnings against the general use of `sudo`.

So, what is the recommended setting for `Library/.../site-packages`?

What is the correct way of handling python packages on my mac?

How do I get out of this mess without destroying my system python?